# How to speed up Collaborative Filtering in Neo4j Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, collaborative-filtering

This is based on sample Cypher from Neo4j documentation:

```
MATCH (user:User)-[:ORDERS]->(:Product)<-[:ORDERS]-(otherUser:User)-[:ORDERS]->(recommended:Product)
WHERE NOT (user)-[:ORDERS]->(recommended)
  AND user.id = 171
RETURN distinct recommended.id, count(distinct otherUser.id) as frequency
ORDER BY frequency DESC
LIMIT 200
```

Whereas the following is the improvements I made:

```
MATCH (user:User)-[:ORDERS]->(p:Product)
WHERE user.id = 171
WITH DISTINCT p, user
MATCH (p)<-[:ORDERS]-(otherUser:User)
WITH DISTINCT otherUser, user
MATCH (otherUser)-[:ORDERS]->(recommended:Product)
WHERE NOT (user)-[:ORDERS]->(recommended)
RETURN distinct recommended.id, count(distinct otherUser.id) as frequency
ORDER BY frequency DESC
LIMIT 200
```

Both returns the same result but the second one runs 6 times faster. (but still 3 took seconds on my Macbook)

1. Why the second one run faster?
2. How to speed it up even further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query gets the `p` products (that you do not want to recommend), but eventually drops them. Instead of dropping them, those `p` nodes could be used to compare against the `recommended` nodes, avoiding the additional DB hits needed to process `WHERE NOT (user)-[:ORDERS]->(recommended)` (which has to rescan every order for `user` every time). That should speed up your query significantly.

Try this:

```
MATCH (user:User)-[:ORDERS]->(p:Product)<-[:ORDERS]-(otherUser:User)
WHERE user.id = 171
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT otherUser) AS others, COLLECT(DISTINCT p) AS sharedProds
UNWIND others AS other
MATCH (other)-[:ORDERS]->(recommended:Product)
WHERE NOT recommended IN sharedProds
RETURN DISTINCT recommended.id, count(DISTINCT other) as frequency
ORDER BY frequency DESC
LIMIT 200;
```

Also, I assume that `User` nodes have unique `id` values, so I use `count(DISTINCT otherUser)` instead of `count(DISTINCT otherUser.id)`, which should be faster.

Comment: Great, it run significantly faster! Little correction: `RETURN DISTINCT recommended.id, count(DISTINCT other) as frequency`

Comment: I wonder why do you need to use `UNWIND` there? What's the different with the following?

`MATCH (user:User)-[:ORDERS]->(p:Product)<-[:ORDERS]-(otherUser:User)
WHERE user.id = 171
WITH distinct otherUser, COLLECT(DISTINCT p) AS sharedProds
MATCH (otherUser)-[:ORDERS]->(recommended:Product)
WHERE NOT recommended IN sharedProds
WITH DISTINCT recommended, COUNT(DISTINCT otherUser) AS frequency
RETURN DISTINCT recommended.id, frequency
ORDER BY frequency DESC
LIMIT 200`

Comment: You have to aggregate the `other` too if you want to get the whole collection of distinct `products` in one alias. To keep one `otherUser` per row, you just perform a `COLLECT` and `UNWIND`, and then each row has one `otherUser` and the full list of `Products`. However, for your query it's unnecessary, I believe, so your edit should work fine too (but of course profile and see which one works better)

Answer (score 1):

The first query is potentially slower than necessary because it applies `DISTINCT` to properties, rather than nodes, which forces the database to look up properties for every single node before potentially dropping them. In the case where the `id` property is unique to a single `User` node (and the same for `Product` nodes), this is going to be less efficient. This would be the faster version of the same query, if you can assume that no `User` shares an `id` with another `User`, and no `Product` shares an `id` with another `Product`:

```
MATCH (user:User)-[:ORDERS]->(:Product)<-[:ORDERS]-(otherUser:User)-[:ORDERS]->(recommended:Product)
WHERE NOT (user)-[:ORDERS]->(recommended)
  AND user.id = 171
WITH recommended, COUNT(DISTINCT otherUser) AS frequency
RETURN recommended.id, frequency
ORDER BY frequency DESC
LIMIT 200
```

Your query applies `DISTINCT` to the nodes at each step, so it avoids this property lookup issue (which is often the most expensive part of a query, especially a large one). However, manually chopping up a long path like that is going to potentially slow down the query, because the planner may not be able to see optimizations it could perform with the whole path. Single long paths are preferable to multiple short paths in almost every instance.

As to how to go even faster, well, just remember that graphs can be resource intensive, so if you're running it in parallel on a laptop or a small cloud instance, maybe take a look at [performance tuning](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-performance-tuning/) to see if you might be choking your database a bit.

EDIT: If you have a densely-connected graph (lots of shared `:Product` nodes between `:User`s) then you may be generating unnecessary result rows with the first query as well. If a `PROFILE` shows a large number of result rows in the middle of your query, try this alternative instead:

```
MATCH (user:User {id:171})-[:ORDERS]->(:Product)<-[:ORDERS]-(otherUser:User)
WITH DISTINCT user, otherUser
MATCH (otherUser)-[:ORDERS]->(recommended:Product)
WHERE NOT (user)-[:ORDERS]->(recommended)
WITH recommended, COUNT(DISTINCT otherUser) AS frequency
RETURN recommended.id, frequency
ORDER BY frequency DESC
LIMIT 200
```

That ensures that each `otherUser` node is only checked once for recommendations, whereas the first query would process each `otherUser` once for every `:Product` they shared with the user. That's the kind of information about your graph that a `PROFILE` can help you turn up; find a step where the result row count blows up and see if there's a way to break it up to reduce total rows.

Comment: Great! It's 2x-3x faster than the first one! But still twice of the second one.

Comment: I'd have to see a `PROFILE` of the query on your setup to tell any further, there are practical factors that could have an impact in this case.